# Pivoting a column in oracle

Tags: oracle, pivot

I have a table with 4 columns `name`, `gender`, `age` and `hair_color`.
`hair_color` has 3 options `Blond`, `Black` and `Brown`.

Can I use the `pivot` command to generate a table with columns `name`, `gender`, `age`, `blond`, `black` and `brown` with the same number of rows.

Comment: Can you share sample input and expected output?

Comment: Difficult to do the formatting. But the extra columns would have 0 and 1 depending on the hair colour, so if person had black hair the black column would have a 1 otherwise it would be 0.

Comment: Add it in the post itself. It's unreadable here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
from FOURCOLUMNTABLE
pivot (
  count(HAIR_COLOR) as HC
  for HAIR_COLOR in ('Blond','Black','Brown')
)
```